# why foo: { bar: 10} prints 10 when executed in chrome console | Javascript

Tags: javascript

Being familiar with object literal after seeing the below code I guessed the last line will be "2 + 2 + 2 = 6" but when executed in chrome console, I got "Nan" as result. Initially I didn't recognize the ":" after the foo in line #4 and the semi colon next to bar in line #5 and #6. To find out why, I tried "foo: { bar: 10}" and then it printed 10. Then I came to know that the syntax is wrong but couldn't understand why it didn't throw an error and instead got an answer 10.

```js
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

foo: {
    bar: 2;
    baz: ++bar;
};
foo.baz + foo.bar + bar;
```

Comment: What piece of code?

Comment: We could use some more details. How is that code running? Can you provide a snippet to reproduce the issue? As it is right now, this question can't be answered.

Comment: Can we get more details? The code, the environment you are running it in?

Comment: looks like some labels.

Answer (score 4):

`foo:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). It does nothing since it isn't labeling anything useful.

`{}` is a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). It groups some statements, but (in this example) not in a significant way. (Important: It is a *block*, not an object literal.)

`bar:` is another label. Ditto for `foo:`.

`10` is a Number.

Since everything else does nothing significant, you are basically evaluating `10` so you get `10` as the result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but what is a label in JS. Might sound silly to you. Do you mean that it is just some string? If so why it is not printed

Comment: @ankamsarav — Labels are described in detail at the other end of the link I put in the answer. They are used mainly to break out of nested loops.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, This helps. Liked the way you have broken the explanation. It's my bad to jump immediately :)